# Parameter displayed out of card

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I have a search card to search through some profiles. For some reason,one parameter is shown out of the card like shown below:
[image]

Even if I exchange the spot of Major and Job type, Major will be displayed out of the card. I'm using the materialize framework. What is the reason for this issue?

My code to show this is:

```
    <div class="col s12 m6 l3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content center">
                <div style="margin-top: -20px; width: 113%; height: 40px; background-color: #0288d1;margin-left: -21px;">
                <span class="card-title2">Advanced search</span>
                </div>
                <%= simple_form_for @search do |s| %>
                    <%= s.input :keyword, label: 'Name' %>  
                    <label>College</label>
                    <%= s.select :college, options_for_select(@college), :include_blank => true %>
                    <%= s.input :min_gpa, label: "Minimum GPA" %>
                    <label>Major</label>
                    <%= s.select :major, options_for_select(@major), :include_blank => true %>
                    <label>Job type</label>
                    <%= s.select :level, options_for_select(@level), :include_blank => true  %>
                    <%= s.button :submit, "Search" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try instead?

```
<%= s.submit 'Search' %>
```

Comment: It changes the submit button, doesnt affect anything else